# How to find value of "CourseCode" that is greater than 200 in XML document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv

I have stored csv file into xml document. I want to find of the values under heading `CourseCode` the values that are 200 or greater.

Comment: At the very least, we would need to see a sample of the xml file.  You should also show us what code you have already tried, so we don't end up repeating things you did previously.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, we need to see how your XML file is structured for sure, but I will still take a wild guess and suggest the following:

```
XDocument.Load("courses.xml").Descendants("CourseCode").Select(o => int.TryParse(o.Value, out int value) ? value : 0).Where(n => n >= 200)
```

This assumes that for a CSV like this:

```
Column1,Column2,...,CourseCode,...,ColumnN
...,...,...,value1,...,...
...,...,...,value2,...,...
...,...,...,value3,...,...
```

You want an `IEnumerable` like this (for values greater than 200): `{value1,value2,value3,...}`

Comment: Philip, this will return an IEnumerable of integers, not the elements you actually want. That's why it's important for the OP to include some examples.

Comment: I thought the OP wanted a list of course codes, which is what the integers in the list stand for...